# What is the file path to use to be able to read the file using Python script

Tags: python, file

My Python script is in the **src** folder and my file is in **res** folder. What is the file path to use to be able open this file ?

```
name = "test"
open("res\\"+name+".json")
```

Despite there is file **test.json** in res folder,I got this error, `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'res\\test.json'`

Dirs structure

```
--main dir\
---- src\
---- res\
```

Comment: Show us the relationship between the `src` and `res` folders.

Comment: @TomZych updated

Comment: The Python script is running in src. There is no res folder in src. So it can't resolve the path. Run the script in main dir.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the src folder is. It matters what the current working directory of the Python process is. Show us the output of `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Robᵩ has a point. I assume you're running the program from `src`, but of course it could be run from any folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as written is telling the program to look in a folder
`src\\res`, because the path is relative to the current path, which is
`src`.

Instead, try this:

```
open("..\\res\\"+name+".json")
```

This means, go up one folder level (`..`), then go to `res`.